# Hack game ini file

Tags: ini

Yesterday was trying to hack `stats.ini` file in Men of War 2 to add experience.

`stats.ini` have attribute [Stats] with lines like: `experience_usa_v0.5 = FA000000FA`

`FA000000FA` value means 250 experience. In 16-system FA = 250 in 10-system.

I was trying change this value by converting numbers like 1000 and 10000 in 16-system and saving in .ini file. But not one of my variants was right.

Then, I rise next level in game and my experience changed to `5E0100005F = 350` in game.

Can someone help me to understand how I can enter some my value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not like anybody should be telling you that cheating is bad (insert Zoidberg meme here), but while working with these things you should understand the concept of higher and lower bytes.

FA000000FA is composed of 5 bytes: 2 first for score, 2 last for checksum and 1 in the middle I have no idea what's for

250 = FA. To be precise, 00 FA - 
this way when you swap bits you get FA 00

5E0100005F  is 350
350=01 5E (when swapped it's 5E01)

It looks like control sum is sum of higher and lower bit (based on your data). In your case:

00 + FA = 00 FA

01 + 5E = 00 5F

This suggests that value for 1000 (in hex 03 E8 ) would be 
E8 03 00 00 EB

But that's just my guess.